# Echoing an echo option

Tags: linux, bash

Today I was testing a script and for some reason I needed to print `-n` to the console.

I tried `echo -n`, which of course just echos without a new line.
I tried `echo "-n"`, which does the same.

Then I tried assigning to a variable:
`str="-n"`. Of course `echo $str` and `echo "$str"` do nothing.

How would you echo exactly `-n`?

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: @Barmar This won't work, `printf '-n'
-bash: printf: -n: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]`

Comment: @JayStanley Don't skip the format string.

Comment: Related: [echo "-n" will not print -n?](/q/13258664/4518341)

Comment: Dupe of [StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168095/how-do-i-print-e-with-echo) which has solutions with both `printf` and `echo`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `printf` rather than `echo`

```
printf '%s\n' '-n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could escape (`\`) both of those characters, telling your shell to read them both as literal characters.

Running `echo \-\n` gives me `-n` as output.

Comment: Escaping it for the shell doesn't prevent `echo` from treating the `-` as an option indicator. And different versions of `echo` behave differently, so what works for your version may not for others -- see [this answer on U&L about `printf` vs `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819). (BTW, use [backticks to invoke code format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).)